# T32: Getting platform device or netdev structure in Linux

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Is there any way to get to the platform device structure of a netdev struture based on the driver compatible  or the network interface name eg: eth0, eth1 etc ?

I want to get this from the T32 after loading a ramdump.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Yes, but you put `Trace32` here and Lauterbach. Do you mean from inside of the tool?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I mean inside the T32 tool, after loading a ram dump.